# flutter ignors alertdialog in catch if there is finally

Tags: flutter, dart

writing an alertdialog inside a catch but if there is a finally it just ignores the alert dialog. the print just shows and escaping the dialog? and if I removed the finally it just works fine. help why this happening.

```
catch(error){
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (ctx)=> AlertDialog(
      title: Text("An ERROR accurred!"),
      content: Text(error.toString()),
      actions: [
        FlatButton(onPressed: (){Navigator.of(ctx).pop();}, child: Text("OK"))
      ],
    ),
    );
    print(error.toString()+"from alert");
  }
  finally{
    setState(() {
  _isLoading = false;
      });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

Comment: In the final case should I expect action in dialog? If this is asynchronous execution, finally is not waiting for your dialogue. If finally has to wait for action in his dialog then I added await in front of the showdialog and async in the upper catch function.

Comment: can you post full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`finally` will be fired depending on any result.
How your code is working actually : First, `catch` is fired, `showDialog` is executed and dialog is shown, then `print` is executued. After these operation, `finally` section is exectued and `Navigator.of(context).pop()` pop (hide) your dialog. And since it is fast, you think your dialog is not shown.

Comment: Then how to wait until "OK" is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The showDialog Widget also returns a Future so this means you need to use await until this code is executed before going to the finally block.

do it this way...

```
...
} catch (error) {
    await showDialog<Null>(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Something whent wrong'),
        content: const Text('An Error ocurred'),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            child: const Text('Okay'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  } finally { ....
```